# Padding of a child doesn't work, image always stay middle

Tags: html, css

There's a problem in my code attached below:

The img with id listItemProfile stays always in middle no matter what padding I set, I though it might due to there's some padding in its parent, but I couldn't find any, any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<style type="text/css">
.accordionOm {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 30px;
  margin: 0;
  font: 300 18px 'Oswald', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.accordionOm:hover {
  color: #000;
}
.accordionOm:before,
.accordionOm:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: #333;
  display: inline-block;
}
.accordionOm:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
  top: 22px;
}
.accordionOm:after {
  width: 2px;
  height: 20px;
  left: 9px;
  top: 13px;
  transition: transform .5s;
  transform: rotate(0);
}
.accordionOm.opened:after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.accordionOm + div {
  border-left: 4px solid #999;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  font: 13px 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #666;
}

* {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #665544;
    text-align: center;}
   body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
   }
   

  #trailBar{
   margin-left: 35px;
   margin-right: 35px;
   margin-top: 25px;
   margin-bottom: 25px;
   height: 180px;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #31a7de, #31a7de 35px, white 35px, white);
      border: transparent;
      border-radius:0.25em;
  }


  p.trailTextTop{
   padding-top: 25px;
   padding-left: 25px;
   padding-right: 60px;
   padding-bottom: 25px;
   font-size: large;
  }

  p.trailTextBot{
  
   padding-left: 25px;
   padding-right: 60px;
   padding-bottom: 25px;
   font-size: large;

  }

  .left { float: left; }
  .right { float: right; }
  p { overflow: hidden; }

  .panel-group .list-group {
   margin-bottom: 0;
  }

  .panel-group .list-group .list-group-item {
   border-radius: 0;
   border-left: none;
   border-right: none;
  }

  .panel-group .list-group .list-group-item:last-child {
   border-bottom: none;
  }
   
  .panel-body{
   background: #efefef;
  }

  #listItem{
   position: relative;
   height: 200px;
   background: #efefef;
  }
  
  #listItemProfile{
   position: absolute;
   height: 80px;
   width: 80px;
   padding-top: 60px;
   padding-bottom: 60px;
   padding-left: 35px;

  }
  
  #listItemTitle{

  }
  
  #listItemSubtitle{

  }

  #listItemInfo{

  }

  #listItemArrow{

  }

</style>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 class="accordionOm opened">
<div id="listItem">

  <img id = "listItemProfile" src="images/Portrait.png">

  
  <div id="listItemTitle">
   
  </div>
  
  <div id="listItemSubtitle">
   
  </div>
  
  <div id="listItemInfo">
   
  </div>

  <div id="listItemArrow">
   
  </div>

</div>
</h4>
<div>

 
    <div id="trailBar">
    <p class="trailTextTop"><span class='left'>Good morning, I just start my first day trip. Happy pedal!</span></p>

       <p class="trailTextBot"><span class='left'>Time 7:20</span><span class='right'>45 Miles</span></p>

    </div>

    <div id="trailBar">
    <p class="trailTextTop"><span class='left'>Good morning, I just start my first day trip. Happy pedal!</span></p>

       <p class="trailTextBot"><span class='left'>Time 7:20</span><span class='right'>45 Miles</span></p>

    </div>

    <div id="trailBar">
    <p class="trailTextTop"><span class='left'>Good morning, I just start my first day trip. Happy pedal!</span></p>

       <p class="trailTextBot"><span class='left'>Time 7:20</span><span class='right'>45 Miles</span></p>

    </div>
</div>
<h4 class="accordionOm">Accordian heading</h4>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing elit. Nullam dignissim convallis est. Quisque aliquam. Donec faucibus. Nunc iaculis suscipit dui. Nam sit amet sem. Aliquam libero nisi, imperdiet at, tincidunt nec, gravida vehicula, nisl. Praesent mattis, massa
    quis luctus fermentum, turpis mi volutpat justo, eu volutpat enim diam eget metus.</p>
</div>

<h4 class="accordionOm">Accordian heading</h4>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing elit. Nullam dignissim convallis est. Quisque aliquam. Donec faucibus. Nunc iaculis suscipit dui. Nam sit amet sem. Aliquam libero nisi, imperdiet at, tincidunt nec, gravida vehicula, nisl. Praesent mattis, massa
    quis luctus fermentum, turpis mi volutpat justo, eu volutpat enim diam eget metus.</p>
</div>

<h4 class="accordionOm">Accordian heading</h4>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing elit. Nullam dignissim convallis est. Quisque aliquam. Donec faucibus. Nunc iaculis suscipit dui. Nam sit amet sem. Aliquam libero nisi, imperdiet at, tincidunt nec, gravida vehicula, nisl. Praesent mattis, massa
    quis luctus fermentum, turpis mi volutpat justo, eu volutpat enim diam eget metus.</p>
</div>
</body>
<script>
$('.accordionOm').next().hide();
$(".opened").next().show();
$('.accordionOm').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("opened") == true) {
    $(this).next().slideUp("slow");
    $(this).removeClass('opened');
  } else {
    $(".opened").next().slideUp("slow");
    $(".opened").removeClass("opened");
    $(this).addClass('opened');
    $(this).next().slideDown("slow");
  }
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You can go with the margin option or change the position: absolute to position:relative for the itemProfile

Comment: Thanks folks, turns out that only use padding-left will never work, I need to  use left: 35px to indicate the padding I want, thanks to you all!

Comment: Padding will not work on inline elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi now define this css

```
#listItemProfile {
    position: absolute;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    /* padding-top: 60px; */
    /* padding-bottom: 60px; */
    /* padding-left: 35px; */
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -40px; // your total width img / 2
    margin-top: -40px;  // your total height img /2
}
```

Comment: Thank you! turns out that only use padding-left will never work, I need to use left: 35px to indicate the padding I want

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `css` given below :

```
#listItemProfile {
    position: absolute;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -40px;
    margin-top: -40px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  turns out that only use padding-left will never work, I need to use left: 35px to indicate the padding I want

Answer (score -1):

try with margin-left , margin-right

Example

```
.class-name{
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:50px;
}
```